# Creating a Value List Using Values from Another Table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a simple database application that records contacts (name, address, etc.). I am trying to draw on various other tables to generate value lists for the forms. Then I would like to have all form values entered by the user to be saved into the appropriate tables on submit.

For example, I have the `people` table which includes the name and address. I have a `title` table with the different possible values for the title (i.e. Mr., Mrs., Ms. Dr.). Upon filling in the contact form, I would like to generate the values for the title field in the form from the title table. I am trying to do this one model for Contact that includes separate classes for the people table and the title table.

In my ContactController.php I have:

```
class ContactController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {

        $people = Contact::all();

        // return main homepage for Contacts section
        return view('pages.contacts.home', compact('people'));


    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $title = Contact::lists('title', 'id');
        return view('pages.contacts.create');
    }
```

In my Contact.php model I have the following:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model {

    protected $table = 'people';

    protected $fillable = [

        'title_id', 
        'name_first',
        'name_middle',
        'name_last',
        'date_birth',
        'date_death',
        'bio',
        'created_at',
        'modified_at'

    ];

    public function title() {

        return $this->belongsTo('Title', 'title_id', 'id');

    }
}


class Title extends Model {

    protected $table = 'title';

    protected $fillable = [

        'title',
        'created_at',
        'modified_at'

    ];

    public function contacts() {

        return $this->hasMany('Contact', 'title_id', 'id');

    }

}
```

In the form I have the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('title', 'Title: ') !!}
    {!! Form::select('title', $title) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('name_first', 'First Name: ') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name_first', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('name_middle', 'Middle Name: ') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name_middle', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('name_last', 'Last Name: ') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name_last', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('name_nick', 'Nickname: ') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name_nick', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

I am getting an error saying the variable `title` is undefined. I cannot determine why the value list is not being returned. Are my relationships returned incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't pass the **$title** variable to your view.

In your create method in the ContactController, assign the **$title** variable to your view:

```
public function create()
    {
        $title = Contact::lists('title', 'id');
        return view('pages.contacts.create')->with('title', $title);
    }
```

See http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views for more documentation.

Comment: I made that change, but I get this error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'title' in 'field list' (SQL: select `title`, `id` from `people`)

I want it to draw the title value list from the title table and not from the people table. What do I have wrong here?

Comment: Do you want to display all the titles on the form? Because than you should change $title = Contact::lists('title', 'id'); to $title = Title::lists('title', 'id');

Comment: Ok, but in that case I get the error: FatalErrorException in ContactController.php line 44:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Title' not found

Comment: I don't have a TitleController.php.  I only have ContactController.php.

Comment: @mattbowlby Your models are in the \App namespace.  Your controllers are in the \App\Http\Controllers namespace.  You need to tell the controller where the model is, either by a `use` statement at the top of the file (`use \App\Title;`), or by fully qualifying the model name when using it (`$title = \App\Title::lists('title', 'id');`)

Comment: Ok, great. I used $title = \App\Title::lists('title', 'id');  - However, I was wondering if I could do it without creating a separate model for the title table (Title.php). I wanted to include the logic for people and title in the Contact.php model.

Comment: There are different approaches for that, but it all depends on the requirements of your application.

For example if it's common in your application that users can create new titles, your approach with two separate models and a defined relationship between them is a good approach.

If the titles are predefined in your application and will never (or maybe have to add one later) will change, maybe an enum field with all titles in the Contact table will be better, so you don't have that extra Title model and table.